# How would I keep a live database directory atomically synchronized with other local disks on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, sync, database, postgresql

I run PostgreSQL 14.1 on Windows 10 (Pro). The computer has multiple internal storage disks. The PostgreSQL "data directory" is set to `C:\whatever\PGDB`.

I do make full backups daily, but unless the `C:` drive dies one nanosecond after the daily backup has taken place, I will obviously lose some data, which I'm trying to avoid.

I want to make it so that the `C:\whatever\PGDB` directory tree is "atomically" mirrored at all times to:

```
D:\mirror\PGDB
E:\mirror\PGDB
F:\mirror\PGDB
```

That is, not the entire drives. Just that directory tree on `C`, with the mentioned ones on other local drives.

I have already asked the PostgreSQL people about this, and unfortunately, PostgreSQL itself does not support this. They wanted me to use RAID, but I have no RAID hardware or software (other than whatever might be built into Windows 10).

I do use `ROBOCOPY` all the time, and it could indeed very well be used to "mirror" directory trees, **BUT** the issue is that `ROBOCOPY` has to be executed as a command; it does not run constantly in the background. I believe I have read somewhere that you simply cannot copy the PG datadir with any "normal"/user-level tool, due to the way it's constantly written to by the database itself.

I need for the mirror PGDB directory trees to be *identical* to the main/"real" one, which is actively being used by PostgreSQL all the time. The purpose is to be able to just copy any of the other drives' PGDB directory tree onto a new `C:` drive when the day comes when it stops working.

My feeling about this is that it has to be something very "low-level" in the operating system which is sure to be able to guarantee that there are no differences, ever, between the original and the mirrors.

I don't have any money and I would strongly prefer to not have to install any extra software, even if free. I would also prefer if the solution is a simple command (or series of commands), rather than having to click around GUI elements.

Comment: "I want to make it so that the C:\whatever\PGDB directory tree is "atomically" mirrored at all times to:" - I believe PostgreSQL supports synchronization between multiple databases. It's called PostgreSQL Sync Replication

Comment: @Ramhound I have no idea what the manual is talking about regarding that. What exactly does it want me to do?

Comment: The correct way to do replication of a database is using the systems tools for this. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/runtime-config-replication.html

Comment: Replicating an **open** database via a utility such as robocopy may result in a damaged database. Not advised.